# How to write test class for to check available record type for profile in apex test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
public static String recordTypeList() {
    List<String> recordType = new List<String> ();
    for (RecordTypeInfo info : Case.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos()) {
        if (info.isAvailable() && (info.developerName == 'recType' || info.developerName == 'recType2')) {
            recordType.add(info.getRecordTypeId() + ':' + info.getName ());
        }
    }
    return JSON.serialize(recordType);
}
```

Comment: Your apex method was beyond saving, but I hope this is the code which you were trying to paste?

Comment: I need test class for this method

Comment: Did you try anything? This is not a code providing site, we can help you if you are stuck anywhere. Did you try calling this method from your test class?

Comment: Yes I tried to get record type id. Id caseId = schema..SobjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(rectype).getRecordTypeId.   This is returning id of record type but I don't know how can I check this is available for profile or not

Comment: If you just call this method from test class, it will return you the result. Please share your exact issue what is happening when you try to call this from test class.

Comment: No. Actually my requirement is one object can have multiple record type but I need to display only 2 specific record type (like Master and child) but those record type also needs to display only who have the access. I need test class for this scenario which is the above class method I have given.